# Repeating an IF statement with multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that adds 1 to a cell in Column 53 (Column BA) if the row below it has a cell that contains a bracketed number "(2)" and another cell that contains the word "Adult".

It goes like this:

```
Sub BUBFindAdults2()

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To lastRow

  If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3), "(2)") <> 0 _
  And InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31), "Adult") <> 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 1, 53).Value = _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 1, 53).Value + 1
  End If

Next x

End Sub
```

However, I also need it to add 1 to the same cell if **two** rows below contains "(3)" and "Adult". *And* if **three** rows below contains "(4)" and "Adult". And so on. You see the pattern!

So far, I've got around this by just repeating the same code as follows:

```
Sub BUBFindAdults2()

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To lastRow

  If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3), "(2)") <> 0 _
  And InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31), "Adult") <> 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 1, 53).Value = _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 1, 53).Value + 1
  End If

  If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3), "(3)") <> 0 _
  And InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31), "Adult") <> 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 2, 53).Value = _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 2, 53).Value + 1
  End If

  If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3), "(4)") <> 0 _
  And InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31), "Adult") <> 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 3, 53).Value = _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - 3, 53).Value + 1
  End If

Next x

End Sub
```

You can probably tell that this starts to get a bit silly when I'm dealing with 10+ repetitions! I know one of the main rules of writing VBA is avoiding repeated code. I've looked at a few other examples of people looping their code but I haven't had any luck applying the methods to my own.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without writing the code for you ... you have a relationship between the number you are looking for and the number of rows below (the former is one more than the latter) so see if you can make a stab with a loop that extends as far as the number of rows you want to check.

Comment: @SJR thanks for the hints! It definitely helps to have it explained like that.

Comment: PS. Many thanks to everyone for your replies. I'm picking @Chris as the accepted answer as his code is most similar to the original and he answered first. However both answers below work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get your code to run, but this can easily be achieved using a nested for loop. See the below code, which will execute 10 repetitions, based on the code you provided in the question:

```
Sub BUBFindAdults2()

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To lastRow     
  If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31), "Adult") <> 0 Then      
    For i = 1 To 10
      If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3), "(" & (i+1) & ")") <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - i, 53).Value = _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x - i, 53).Value + 1
      End If
    Next i
  End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good improvement of the code, but maybe you can also move that check for `"Adult"` outside the loop? (of `i`).

Comment: @Peter, many thanks for your reply. This works perfectly if I change the plus signs in "(" + (i+1) + ")" to ampersands, ie. "(" & (i+1) & ")". Thanks!

Comment: @A.S.H Good point, thanks. Antony, I've updated the code with that change to improve efficiency. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can first use a filter on the column `31` to have only the rows where `"Adult"` appears. After that it becomes somehow simpler, and surely faster.

```
Sub BUBFindAdults2()
    With Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
       .AutoFilter 31, "*Adult*"
       Dim r As Range, i As Integer
       For Each r In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
         For i = 2 To 4
            If r.Cells(3) Like "*(" & i & ")*" Then
                With r.Offset(1 - i).Cells(53)
                    .Value = .Value + 1
                End With
            End If
         Next
       Next
      .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it might have to be `.Cells(,3)` and `.Cells(,53)` but can't test it

Comment: @Slai it works, I'm indexing the cells collection in a unidimensional range (a full row).. The code is unit-tested btw.

Comment: @A.S.H, this works perfectly. Hadn't thought of using the filter, that's a great idea.